# Inserting a TIMESTAMP value in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-insert

Hello I'm having a trouble inserting this value in Oracle SQL Developer Version 19.4.0.354.

> **'2013-01-01 00:00:00.0000'**

Here is the value that I want to insert in one of my tables.

I tried DATE and TIMESTAMP data types but they don't work. I also tried altering the sessions and other possible solutions all over the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Column datatype should be `TIMESTAMP`. Use appropriate format mask in `TO_TIMESTAMP` function.

```
SQL> create table test (col timestamp);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (col) values (to_timestamp('2013-01-01 00:00:00.0000', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss:ff6'));

1 row created.
```

What's in there? (`alter session` is here just to display the result in desired format; it doesn't affect the value stored in that column):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff6';

Session altered.

SQL> select * From test;

COL
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
01.01.2013 00:00:00.000000

SQL>
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest approach is to use a *literal* timestamp, so you don't rely on implicit conversion:

```
select timestamp '2013-01-01 00:00:00.0000' from dual;
```

You can also use `to_timestamp()`:

```
select to_timestamp('2013-01-01 00:00:00.0000', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss:ff4') from dual;
```

On the other hand, if you really want to work with a string, then you would need to change the nls setting to your own format before:

```
alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss:ff4';
```

You can then use pass your string value directly in the query, and Oracle will implicitly convert it to the target datatype while inserting.

Answer (score 0):

You have no time component, so I would just use:

```
date '2013-01-01'
```

This is the safest syntax (and clearest and standard too!) for providing a date value.

If Oracle wants a timestamp, it will convert this correctly.